# Do not apply text-transsform on Placeholder IE10

Tags: html, css, input, internet-explorer-10, placeholder

I'm applying `text-transform:uppercase;` to an input field, which is capitalizing my placeholder content also. I'm able to avoid this in firefox and chrome. But not able to stop the same in IE10. Please see the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhh31gLo/2/).

Comment: you want to enter the text in small-letter ? is this what u want ?

Comment: if the above thing u want is. It is working for me as I am changing the text-transform. It is working in IE 10 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for IE placeholder is 
`input:-ms-input-placeholder {text-transform: lowercase;}`

Comment: i've updated my fiddle with that change. yet no luck http://jsfiddle.net/jhh31gLo/5/

Comment: You are missing `input` between ms and placeholder. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/turbolihis/jhh31gLo/9/